# Oozie launching MR jobs as YARN user instead of given user name

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, oozie

I have designed a Oozie workflow to run a Sqoop script.
I'm submitting the workflow using the user name given by hadoop admin team.

Script is failing because oozie is launching MR jobs as YARN user which is not able to access my userid directory in HDFS i.e /user/cv1100.

I checked the MR log there I can see the property as "user.name=yarn"
How can I change this? I have mentioned "user.name" in job.properties file of Oozie.

Below is the error I’m getting in logs, check if it helps

```
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.CLA
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "CLA".
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.CLA
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "CLA".
error: error reading /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/smore.jar; /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/smore.jar (Permission denied)
error: error   reading /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/adfs.jar; /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/adfs.jar (Permission denied)
error: error reading /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/aftp.jar; /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/aftp.jar (Permission denied)
error: error reading /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/janusclient.jar; /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/janusclient.jar (Permission denied)
error: error reading /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/adfs-api-loader.jar; /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/adfs-api-loader.jar (Permission denied)
error: error reading /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/aster-networking.jar; /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/aster-networking.jar (Permission denied)
Note: /tmp/sqoop-yarn/compile/a9988b6ea5448f4cc962b625361feb1a/test.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Intercepting System.exit(1)
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1]

31075 [Thread-35] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  - Loading data to table ecsdashboard.test_oozie
31175 [Thread-35] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  - Failed with exception Unable to move sourcehdfs:///user/qjdht93/test/_SUCCESS to destination hdfs://apps/hive/warehouse/ecsdashboard.db/test_oozie/_SUCCESS
31176 [Thread-35] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  - FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask
31728 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool  - Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Hive exited with status 1
at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeExternalHiveScript(HiveImport.java:385)
at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeScript(HiveImport.java:335)
at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.importTable(HiveImport.java:239)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:425)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:506)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:222)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:231)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:240)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.runSqoopJob(SqoopMain.java:206)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.run(SqoopMain.java:174)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:38)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.main(SqoopMain.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:225)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1594)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
Intercepting System.exit(1)

<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<

Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1]

Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully

Oozie Launcher, uploading action data to HDFS sequence file: hdfs://Had1:8020/user/qjdht93/oozie-oozi/0000054-150404155202480-oozie-oozi-W/sqoop2hive--sqoop/action-data.seq

Oozie Launcher ends


Log Type: syslog 

Log Length: 2914 

2015-04-14 02:49:11,912 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2015-04-14 02:49:11,943 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSinkAdapter: Sink ganglia started
2015-04-14 02:49:12,012 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2015-04-14 02:49:12,012 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: MapTask metrics system started
2015-04-14 02:49:12,024 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Executing with tokens:
2015-04-14 02:49:12,024 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Kind: mapreduce.job, Service: job_1428177121154_1938, Ident: (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.token.JobTokenIdentifier@45d1f40c)
2015-04-14 02:49:12,048 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Kind: RM_DELEGATION_TOKEN, Service: 39.7.48.3:8050, Ident: (owner=qjdht93, renewer=oozie mr token, realUser=oozie, issueDate=1428994143490, maxDate=1429598943490, sequenceNumber=253, masterKeyId=11)
2015-04-14 02:49:12,100 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Sleeping for 0ms before retrying again. Got null now.
2015-04-14 02:49:12,383 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: mapreduce.cluster.local.dir for child: /data2/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/qjdht93/appcache/application_1428177121154_1938,/data3/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/qjdht93/appcache/application_1428177121154_1938,/data4/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/qjdht93/appcache/application_1428177121154_1938,/data5/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/qjdht93/appcache/application_1428177121154_1938,/data6/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/qjdht93/appcache/application_1428177121154_1938,/data7/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/qjdht93/appcache/application_1428177121154_1938,/data8/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/qjdht93/appcache/application_1428177121154_1938,/data9/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/qjdht93/appcache/application_1428177121154_1938,/data10/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/qjdht93/appcache/application_1428177121154_1938,/data11/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/qjdht93/appcache/application_1428177121154_1938,/data12/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/qjdht93/appcache/application_1428177121154_1938
2015-04-14 02:49:12,821 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
2015-04-14 02:49:13,273 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
2015-04-14 02:49:13,596 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://Had1:8020/user/qjdht93/oozie-oozi/0000054-150404155202480-oozie-oozi-W/sqoop2hive--sqoop/input/dummy.txt:0+5
2015-04-14 02:49:13,622 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 0
2015-04-14 02:49:13,659 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.id
```

Comment: It seems you may set a property in hadoop configuration file or in hadoop-env file.

Comment: HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=%username% check this in hadoop-env.cmd if you are windows user. HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=$USER in hadoop-env.sh if linux.

Comment: thanks..where can i get a list of porperties that can be set in hadoop-env?

Comment: All properties exists in that file itself. Some of the properties commented and others not. Can you solve your problem now?

Comment: actually in /etc/hadoop/conf i can see hadoop-env.cmd which already having HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=%username% and hadoop-env.sh is also present which is also having this property....I'm getting same error no luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75109/discussion-between-chhaya-vishwakarma-and-kumar).

Comment: chat is restricted here..can you suggest something? for the problem I'm facing

Comment: Can you add your full exception? It should be some other problem. Not a username problem.

Comment: added the logs please check

Comment: It seems there is no permission for the directory which contains jar files. error: error reading /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/smore.jar; /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/smore.jar (Permission denied

Comment: Either give full permission for the directory or run the oozie command as sudo.

Comment: as you see below it says unable to move source hdfs<> to target hdfs<> is this error is due to /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/smore.jar; /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/smore.jar (Permission denied ?

Comment: Yes. It should able to read the jar files to work properly. Check it once by giving permission to the directory

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue? 
Launching a Ozzie with shell action (shell will launch a MR/Yarn job) results in the same issue:  (don't understand why its running as YARN instead of the user johndoe)
Diagnostics: Permission denied: user=johndoe, access=EXECUTE, inode="/user/yarn/.staging":yarn:hadoop:drwx------
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkFsPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:271)

Comment: **Also here some snippets from the job launch...**
15/05/18 11:36:07 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Kind: mapreduce.job, Service: job_14319712200_0013, Ident: (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.token.JobTokenIdentifier@3dbb2cc9)

15/05/18 11:36:07 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Kind: **RM_DELEGATION_TOKEN, Service: x.x.x.x:8050, Ident: (owner=johndoe, renewer=oozie mr token, realUser=oozie, issueDate=1431974155327, maxDate=1432578955327, sequenceNumber=18, masterKeyId=2)**

Comment: Sorry, but i didn't find any solution yet If you get anything on it please let me also know

Comment: It works if i am Yarn user.  i.e. sudo su - yarn  and from yarn user prompt if you run, you might not get the error which i was getting.

Comment: I don't have rights to run command with "sudo"

Comment: I have the same exact issue as user "hbr" in the above comment. Diagnostics: Permission denied: user=testuser, access=EXECUTE, inode="/user/yarn/.staging":yarn:hdfs:drwx------
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkFsPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:271). Did you find the fix for this?

Comment: Hadoop administrators did something and its working fine now...